# How to count how many customers is returning and how many is new

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a customer log-in screen with this information

| StartDate | ClientID | cycleID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 100 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 100 |
| 01-10-2022 | 103 | 100 |
| 01-10-2022 | 104 | 100 |
| 01-10-2022 | 105 | 100 |
| 01-11-2022 | 101 | 200 |
| 01-11-2022 | 102 | 200 |
| 01-11-2022 | 104 | 200 |
| 01-11-2022 | 106 | 200 |
| 01-11-2022 | 107 | 200 |

I want to make a reusable system where I can add a base CycleID(100) and a new CycleID(200) and get the count/list of clientID's that is returning and which are new.

I've looked into creating a CTE but was wondering if a UDF can be created in SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can  use conditonal aggregation on a join

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s2."ClientID"  IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) repeat
  ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN s2."ClientID"  IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new_ 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE "cycleID" = 200) s1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE "cycleID" = 100) s2 
ON s1."ClientID" = s2."ClientID"
```

| repeat | new_ |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

you can add Distinct, if you don't want to count the duplicates

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s2."ClientID"  IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) repeat
  ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN s2."ClientID"  IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new_ 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "ClientID" FROM tab1 WHERE "cycleID" = 200) s1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT "ClientID" FROM tab1 WHERE "cycleID" = 100) s2 
ON s1."ClientID" = s2."ClientID"
```

Comment: What if there are duplications of ClientID's how would you calculate the distinct users?

Comment: use DISTINCT like the second query i added shows